# Can the Bonferroni correction or another correction for multiple comparisons be used in a logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, bonferroni

Can the Bonferroni correction or another correction for multiple comparisons be used in a logistic regression? I have only seen it used in ANOVAs. Also, is there a test I can use in SPSS for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be. I don't know SPSS (and questions about software are off topic here) but it ought to be possible there. In any case, Bonferroni is simple to do by hand. Just divide the alpha value by the number of comparisons. So, if you wanted p < 0.05 with 4 comparisons, you would then need 0.0125.